# Routing Error undefined local variable or method `applicationController' for main:Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm following Agile Web Development with Rails 5.1 book.  And I'm trying to upload a picture file. The example in the book doesn't go into the routes.rb in this section, and I'm clearly not getting this part correct, as when loading the browser I get this error:

`Routing Error - undefined local variable or method 'applicationController' for main:Object`

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :orders
  resources :line_items
  resources :carts
  resources :pictures
  root 'store#index', as: 'store_index'

  resources :products do
    get :who_bought, on: :member
  end

  get 'upload/new', to: 'upload#get'
end
```

I have been trying other variations, but always end up with no route matches error:

`get 'upload/new', to: 'upload#new'` or get `'upload/get', to: 'upload#get'`

**upload_controller.rb**

```
class UploadController < applicationController

  def get //the book uses method 'get', would normally expect 'new'
    @picture = Picture.new
  end

  def picture
    @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])
    send_data(@picture.data, filename: @picture.name, type: @picture.content_type, disposition: "inline")
  end

  def save
    @picture = Picture.new(picture_params)
      if @picture.save
        redirect_to(action: 'show', id: @picture.id)
      else
      render(action: :get)
      end
  end

  def show
    @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

    def picture_params
      params.require(:picture).permit(:comment, :upload_picture)
    end

end
```

**model/picture.rb**

Don't expect the model to be causing an issue with the routes, but adding it for completeness.

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_format_of :content_type, with: /|Aimage/, message: "must be a picture"

  def uploaded_picture=(picture_field)
    self.name         = base_part_of(picture_field.original_filename)
    self.content_type = picture_field.content_type.chomp
    self.data         = picture_field.read
  end

  def base_part_of(file_name)
    File.basement(file_name).gsub(/[^|w._-]/, '')
  end
end
```

Comment: Change `class UploadController < applicationController` to `class UploadController < ApplicationController`.

Comment: That seems to have fixed it, thanks!  I now have an error in the form, but that's a different issue ;)

Comment: @Vishal do you want to post as answer?

Comment: I have posted an answer. Some appreciation will be gift for me ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is the naming convention that is going wrong. The controller that you are inheriting from is `ApplicationController` and not `applicationController` According to the naming convention of rails controller's name is always CamelCase. For more naming convention have a look at this [link](https://gist.github.com/iangreenleaf/b206d09c587e8fc6399e)

Here you need to replace `class UploadController < applicationController` to `class UploadController < ApplicationController`

Answer (score 1):

Your writing is incorrect `applicationController` change to like below

```
class UploadController < ApplicationController
```

`application` to `Application`

That's it, hope it helps